# Mobile menu z-index issue?

Tags: css, mobile, menu

I am having issues with my mobile menu, it looks to be a z-index issue as when the menu is toggled, it appears behind the content below. However, I've been playing with this, and I can not get the toggled menu to the front.

Code:
HTML:

```
        <section class="navigation">
            <div class="nav-container">
                <div class="brand">
                    <a href="/" title="Storey &#38; Co. Solicitors" rel="home"><img class="header-image" src="assets/img/storey-and-co-logo.png" alt="Storey &#38; Co. Solicitors" title="Storey &#38; Co. Solicitors"></a>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <div class="nav-mobile">
                        <a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="our-team.html">Our Team</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="services.html">Services</a>
                            <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="divorce.html">Divorce</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="wills.html">Wills</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="residential.html">Residential</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-highlight">
                            <a href="https://www.perfectportal.co.uk" target="_blank">Obtain a Quote</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Jquery

```
        (function($) {
          $(function() {
            $('nav>ul>li').addEventListener('click',function() {
              $(this).children('.nav-dropdown').show();
            });
            $('nav>ul>li').mouseleave(function() {
              $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
            });
          });
            document.querySelector('#nav-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.classList.toggle('active');
          });
          $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
            $('nav ul').toggle();
          });
        })(jQuery);
```

Sass

```
        header
            background: $brand-primary
            height: $nav-height
            clear: both

        section.navigation
            padding: 0px
            clear: both

        nav
          float: right
          ul
            list-style: none
            margin: 0
            padding: 0
            li
              float: left
              position: relative
              a
                display: block
                padding: 0 20px
                line-height: $nav-height
                background: $brand-primary
                color: #fff
                text-decoration: none
                &:hover
                  background: $brand-3-dark
                  color: #fff
                &:not(:only-child):after
                  padding-left: 4px
                  content: ' ▾'
              ul li
                min-width: 190px
                & a
                  padding: 15px
                  line-height: 20px
                  z-index: 1

        .nav-highlight a
            background: $brand-3-dark
            color: #fff

            &:hover
                background: $brand-3-primary

        .nav-dropdown
          position: absolute
          display: none
          z-index: 1
          box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)

        .nav-mobile
          display: none
          position: absolute
          top: 0
          right: 0
          background: $brand-primary
          height: $nav-height
          width: $nav-height

        #nav-toggle
          position: relative
          z-index: 9
          left: 18px
          top: 22px
          cursor: pointer
          padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px
          span,
          span:before,
          span:after
            cursor: pointer
            border-radius: 1px
            height: 5px
            width: 35px
            background: #fff
            position: absolute
            display: block
            content: ''
            transition: all 300ms ease-in-out
          span:before
            top: -10px
          span:after
            bottom: -10px
          &.active span
            background-color: transparent
            &:before,
            &:after
              top: 0
            &:before
              transform: rotate(45deg)
            &:after
              transform: rotate(-45deg)

        @media only screen and (max-width: $breakpoint)
          .nav-mobile
            display: block
          nav
            width: 100%
            padding: $nav-height 0 15px
            ul
              display: none
              li
                float: none
                a
                  padding: 15px
                  line-height: 20px
                ul li a
                  padding-left: 30px
          .nav-dropdown
            position: static

        @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint)
          .nav-list
            display: block !important

        .navigation
          height: $nav-height
          background: $brand-primary

        .nav-container
          max-width: $content-width
          margin: 0 auto

        .brand
          position: absolute
          float: left
          padding-top: 10px
          vertical-align: middle
          text-transform: uppercase
          font-size: 1.4em
          box-sizing: border-box
          a,
          a:visited
            color: #fff
            text-decoration: none

        img.header-image
            max-width: 200px

        @media screen and (max-width: $breakpoint-small)
            img.header-image
                max-width: 175px
                padding-top: 10px
```

And the live version is here: http://staging-maris-storey.transitiongraphics.co.uk/

Help appreciated

Comment: Explain how to reproduce the problem. I don't know what to do in the live version to see the issue

Comment: I think this happens because of the static height in `.navigation` and `header`.

Comment: oh, right, it's in mobile, i was looking in desktop. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a relative position and a higher z-index to your nav:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Maggie Serino answer isn't working for you, because it work when I am testing it. However another solution would be to add `clear:both;` to the first section. The issue is being caused by your fixed height `header`, which is causing the section below not to be pushed down by the dropdown.

```
header + section {
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: I agree both these solutions should work, but something is obviously not quite right still?

Comment: @GrantSmith Have you tried clearing your mobiles browser cache after making the suggested CSS changes?

Comment: Yes, also trying in dev mode on browsers, same issue?

Comment: @GrantSmith That is very odd. I am not sure what to suggest, because when I go into to dev mode in the browser and change the CSS to either of these solutions it fixes your issue.

Comment: I think I had my spacing wrong in sass, now works to a fashion. I think I have jquery issues to sort. Plus I would prefer the menu to cover the content, rather then the content move down. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

@Grant Smith if you'd prefer the menu to cover the content you need to give it an absolute position (and the parent needs to be relative). I've tried a bit on your staging and you should add:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
    // your other attributes
}

.nav-list {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    // your other attributes
}
```

Let me know if it worked.